# Examples of convergence spaces which are not limit spaces, and limit spaces which are not Choquet spaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a (non-empty) set and denote by $\mathbb{F}X$ the set of filters on X. Let $\xi$ be a relation between $X$ and $\mathbb{F}X$.
We say that the pair $(X,\xi)$ is a *convergence space* iff

1. $(x,\mathcal{F}) \in \xi$ and $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{G}$ implies $(x,\mathcal{G}) \in \xi$.
2. $(x,\dot{x}) \in \xi$, where $\dot{x}$ is the filter generated by $\{x\}$, i.e. the filter of all sets containing $x$.

If, in addition, a convergence space satisfies

If $(x,\mathcal{F}) \in \xi$ and $(x,\mathcal{G}) \in \xi$,
then $(x,\mathcal{F} \cap \mathcal{G}) \in \xi$

then $(X,\xi)$ is called a *limit space*.

A convergence space $(X,\xi)$ is a *pseudotopological space (Choquet space)* iff

$(x,\mathcal{F}) \in \xi \iff (x,\mathcal{U}) \in \xi$ for every ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ containing $\mathcal{F}$.

The following inclusions can be shown:

Pseudotopological spaces $\subsetneq$ Limit spaces $\subsetneq$ Convergence spaces.

What are some interesting examples of limit spaces which are not pseudotopological spaces, and of convergence spaces which are not limit spaces?

Comment: Could you add some definitions?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't know if it's going to be of any use, but you could look at https://doi.org/10.1017/S0960129502003699 and https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82169188.pdf If memory serves me right there ought to be some examples and counter-examples in there somewhere.